# Xamarin forms UWP: Exception thrown: 'System.TypeLoadException' in System.Private.CoreLib.ni.dll

Tags: xamarin.forms, typeloadexception

Getting the following exception after updating xamarin forms.

> Exception thrown: 'System.TypeLoadException' in System.Private.CoreLib.ni.dll
>   An exception of type 'System.TypeLoadException' occurred in System.Private.CoreLib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code
>   Could not load type 'Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlResourceIdAttribute' from assembly 'Xamarin.Forms.Core, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

I have this problem after installing xamarin forms 3.1.0.912540 from 2.5.0.121934.

Screenshot adding below:

[image]

Comment: "Version=2.0.0.0" is certainly wrong.  Maybe [this helps](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/126339/upgrading-to-xamarin-forms-3-0-causing-error).

Comment: [clean bin/obj folders](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/334239/#Comment_334239) after closing IDE

Comment: You can use Visual studio installer to install .NET Framework 4.7.1.It  is a software framework,not a nuget package.NuGet is a free and open-source package manager.

Comment: You can try it.I solved it by this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is already reported in the xamarin forums and [the solution](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/334239/#Comment_334239) is to

- Clean all projects in solution
- close Visual Studio
- Remove all `bin` and `obj` folders from all projects (shared and device (Android, iOS, UWP) specific)
- Restart IDE, build the solution.

Comment: Again I am getting the same problem, but this solution is not working

Comment: posted a new question with more details https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53649224/xamarin-forms-system-typeloadexception-clean-remove-bin-and-obj-folders-and