# Xamarin forms: System.TypeLoadException - Clean, remove bin and obj folders and build not working

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp, typeloadexception

I already asked a question about this issue on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53044549/xamarin-forms-uwp-exception-thrown-system-typeloadexception-in-system-privat). But the solution I got there is not working now. **The solution was clean, remove bin and obj folders and rebuild.**

**Exception details:**

> Exception thrown: 'System.TypeLoadException' in System.Private.CoreLib.ni.dll
>   An exception of type 'System.TypeLoadException' occurred in System.Private.CoreLib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code
>   Could not load type 'Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlResourceIdAttribute' from assembly 'Xamarin.Forms.Core, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

**Screenshot:**

[image]

**I have this problem after updating xamarin forms to 3.4.0.1008975 from 2.5.0.121934. Problem is only on the UWP part. Android and IOS apps are working fine, what is the solution for this?**

Comment: does a referenced component have still have any dependency on XF 2.5?

Comment: @magicandre1981 How can I check that?

Comment: Have your updated the xamarin.forms nuget package version in the forms project?

Comment: Yes, updated to 3.4.0.1008975 from 2.5.0.121934.

Comment: Could you mind share a  mini sample?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT Give me some time, i will provide

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT Created a sample project and updated the XF to 3.4.0.1008975, but there is no issue when building the project.

Comment: Could you try to roll  back to  original version?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT For doing the android tabs on bottom I have updated the XF, If I downgrade that feature will break

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT For doing that feature the XF should be 3.1 or above.https://montemagno.com/xamarin-forms-official-bottom-navigation-bottom-tabs-on-android/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184859/discussion-between-nico-zhu-msft-and-sreejith-sree).

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT I got the solution for this. I updated it as the answer. Thanks for your time and support

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this problem in the following way.

I just updated all the other NuGet packages in my project and do clean, delete bin and obj folders and rebuild. Also unload and reload projects, after doing these things that exception vanished away from my project. Somewhere in StackOverflow, I got that the idea of updating all the other NuGet packages.